# Best way to use Slack API script from server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, slack-api, ngrok

I created some internal tools that use Slack API and after testing them locally using ngrok and serveo, I'd like to use a server to allow other colleagues to use the script.

Do I still need to use ngrok or serveo or any other tunnels to forward the traffic using flask? If not, how would that work? I tried using IP or server name but didn't work.

In case tunnel is needed, what would be the best free tool to use? ngrok, serveo or others?

The problem with ngrok is that the free version expires after 8 hours, meaning everytime the session expires, I need to update Request URL, Options Load URL and Slash Commands URLs in Slack api UI, as the URL changes.

Using Serveo gives the option of keeping the same URL (serveo.net). This although didn't seem to be very stable.

I tried to refresh it adding the command to shell script:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:5000 serveo.net
```

But got this message:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. Host key verification failed.
```

Checking online I've tried suggested solutions (mainly using -t -t) but that didn't work, getting:

```
Could not resolve hostname 80:localhost:5000: Name or service not known
```

Comment: You need to host your scripts on the web. If you are looking for an easy and cheap solution check out serverless computing. Can recommend "Now", which works great with Slack and has a free plan. Here is an overview article on geekflare: https://geekflare.com/serverless-computing-platform/

Comment: how does that work? Do I still need to add path to request in slack UI like https://zeit.co/lpath/slack/message_actions or should I use alias like https://alias.now.sh and add the python script to the github repo?

Comment: the latter. connect your gitub repo with the now service and commit your code. You then get a permanent URL to where the code of your repo is hosted. That you can then configure as action_url for your Slack app. e.g. `https://slackappnowdemo.dummy.now.sh/service.php`

Comment: I get error `NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA` with `502: BAD_GATEWAY`. This happens also navigating from browser. It doesn't happen up to https://slackappnowdemo.dummy.now.sh/ or https://slackappnowdemo.dummy.now.sh/folder/ but it does when adding script path https://slackappnowdemo.dummy.now.sh/folder/script.py

Comment: I would check out this page on how to use the Now service with Python: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/python-now-python/?query=pyton

Comment: Hey. Did it work for you?

Comment: I'm stuck installing the modules needed for my script. in the page says `Inside requirements.txt define` so I thought adding a requirements.txt to project would work, but when checking logs, it still installs only the default packages

Comment: Here is a demo setup for a Slack slash command in Python with Now. Maybe it helps you get your stuff working. If not I would suggest opening a new question about your specific issue. https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slacknowdemopython

Comment: the requirements.txt was working this time. But then for some reason slash.py was returning `Method Not Allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL.` so I tried my script and it seems doesn't read the env variables. I'm defining them with `now -e SLACK_BOT_TOKEN='myslackbottoken'` and `now -e SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN='mytoken'` but logs say `module initialization error 'SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'`

Comment: so I managed to make work your example. still need to understand how to define and call env variables in code. my understanding is that I should do something like `now secret add slack-verification-token "dfsaf453452vsdgfg45"
now secret add slack-bot-token "xoxb-3452345324-4564356-dftretert"
now -e SLACK_BOT_TOKEN=@slack-bot-token
now -e SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN=@slack-verification-token` would then need to still call in code like `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]`?

Comment: Yes. I would add the slack token as "secret" to make sure it can not be accessed by anyone else than you and your app. I have not tested this but according to the docs those secrets can be accessed like any other environment variable once created. Just give it a try. and if you get struck on a specific issue please open a new question. (docs: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/environment-variables-and-secrets/?query=environ)

Comment: OK I was curios, so I added an API call with a slack token to my example. Works perfectly using the `secret` feature of now, which is exposed as environment variable to your app. New version is on my github repo.

Comment: it seems this solution can't work as my script is too big so I get `Error: Size of uploaded file exceeds 50MB`

Comment: which means the solution does work, but your files are just bigger than what is allowed by Slack. How about splitting them and uploading parts?

Comment: what do you mean? The script using Slack API works if run locally or from server, so it seems the limit is on Now side

Comment: ah I misread sorry. But 50M is a lot of code :-D The size if your source files are indeed limited on the free edition. If you need more than you need to upgrade to a payed tier. https://zeit.co/pricing Or you can try another serverless platform like Amazon Lamda. Not sure about their limitations though so you want to check up front.